# Getting empty array when querying ObjectId field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**What I have**
I have defined a mongoose schema as follows

```
var favoriteSchema = new Schema({

    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    cars: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Car'
    }]
    }, {
        timestamps: true
    });
```

I have also defined get/post routes for this model/schema:

```
favoriteRouter.route('/')
.get((req,res,next) => {
    Favorites.find({user: req.user.id})
    console.log(req.user.id);
    //.populate('user')
    //.populate('cars')
    .then((favorites) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(favorites);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})
.post((req, res, next) => {
    Favorites.create(req.body)
    .then((favorite) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(favorite);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})
```

**What I need**
The 'get' operation is not working for me. I would like to retrieve all the favourites of a user. The post request is working fine, so I can see the documents stored correctly with the mongo console, but when I perform the get request, I get an empty array.

**What I tried**
· I tried to console.log(req.user.id) to confirm that was correct.
· I also tried not to filter by user -> Favorites.find({}) and this works fine.
· I tried Favorites.find({'name': ...}) and Favorites.find({name: ...}) but none of them work for me either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: .get will not work, you need to remove that console statement from there, you can place it inside the then() block

Comment: @KiranLM, I can't understand what you are asking in your comment

Comment: I've edited the comment, you need to place that console.log inside then block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong

```
Favorites.find({user: req.user.id})
console.log(req.user.id);
//.populate('user')
//.populate('cars')
.then((favorites) => {
```

You have to apply .then to the promise, and now you are applying it to nothing. Try this:

```
console.log(req.user.id);
Favorites.find({user: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id)})
.then((favorites) => {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right, but it was my fault when posting the question. The console.log() statement had to be placed before Favorites.find(......). It is correctly placed in the code that I am executing

Comment: It could be because you aren't finding with ObjectId, but with string. I updated the code

Comment: Ohh... I finally found where the problem was. It has not to do with the code. I did the post operation with one user, and then did the get operation with another user, which really didn't have any 'favourite' stored. Thank you all